# EXCEL VBA Showing a Userform from a Different Worksheet or Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have developed a userform in EXCEL 2016 for PC. If the user launches the userform (from a button my add-in adds to the ribbon) from the same workbook/worksheet as the last launch or show, then I want the userform to remember all the users settings from the last use. Therefore, when the user is finished with a particular use, I simply hide the form. This works well so far.

HOWEVER, if the user shows the userform subsequently from a different worksheet or workbook, then EXCEL "snaps" back to the original workbook/worksheet the userform was launched from. In this case, I want the userform to reset and appear in the "new" active workbook/worksheet.

I can imagine pseudocode like this:

```
Public wb0 As Workbook
Public ws0 As Worksheet

'  IF the userform is being used for the 1st time

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    yada yada yada...

    wb0 = current workbook
    ws0 = current worksheet
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If wb0 <> ActiveWorkbook OR ws0 <> ActiveWorkSheet Then
        (**Force the userform to open in the current workbook/worksheet**)
        Call Reset
        wb0 = current workbook
        ws0 = current worksheet
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I am not sure how to:

1) Test whether the current active workbook and worksheet are the same as the active workbook and worksheet from the last use. Should I set wb0 to the Name property of the ActiveWorkbook?

```
wb0 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

And then the test would be:

```
If wb0 <> ActiveWorkbook.Name ...
```

2) Also, not sure how to force the userform to open in the current worksheet.

====

Or, perhaps it would be best to have something like:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If wb0 <> ActiveWorkbook OR ws0 <> ActiveWorkSheet Then
        Unload userform
        Reload userform
    End If
End Sub
```

That way everything would be automatically reset...

====

Can someone please advise?

Thanks!!

Dan

Comment: You could use a hidden sheet and store all the valus of the userform there and then have the userform fill itself upon initialization. That way it will always work. Its kind fo a hack i guess though

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for the response. So, use a second hidden sheet to store the values and unload the primary sheet every time. Then, re-initialize the primary sheet every time and if values are saved on the second hidden sheet, then re-populate the primary sheet from the second sheet, correct? How does one create a hidden sheet? Is there an easy way to re-populate one sheet from another or does it have to be done for each field in the userform?

Answer (score 2):

I do this with some UserForms in a big add-in.

Imagine a UserForm named F_UserForm. The massively stripped-down module that calls it is shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim gF_UserForm As F_UserForm

Sub CallUserForm()

  If Not gF_UserForm Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    If gF_UserForm.ActiveWkbk.FullName <> ActiveWorkbook.FullName Then
      Unload gF_UserForm
      Set gF_UserForm = Nothing
    End If
  End If

  If gF_UserForm Is Nothing Then
    Set gF_UserForm = New F_UserForm
  End If

  With gF_UserForm
    Set .ActiveWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
    .Show
  End With

End Sub
```

The stripped-down UserForm code is shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim m_Wkbk As Workbook

Public Property Set ActiveWkbk(wkbk As Workbook)
  Set m_Wkbk = wkbk
End Property
```

For the OP's situation, my main routine can be replaced with the following, and the pieces I've added to the userform's code above need not change, but should be incorporated into `Reg_Userform`.

```
Option Explicit

Dim gReg_Userform As Reg_Userform

Sub conRegBox(control As IRibbonControl)

  If Not gReg_Userform Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    If gReg_Userform.ActiveWkbk.FullName <> ActiveWorkbook.FullName Then
      Unload gReg_Userform
      Set gReg_Userform = Nothing
    End If
  End If

  If gReg_Userform Is Nothing Then
    Set gReg_Userform = New Reg_Userform
  End If

  With gReg_Userform
    Set .ActiveWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
    .Show
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your response. I have been studying your approach and I have a few questions:

Comment: 1) So, my add-in only has 1 userform. I believe that this corresponds to your F_Userform and gF_Userform is sort of a dummy copy of F_Userform? Is that correct? If so, I assume I should replace F_Userform with the name of my userform Reg_Userform. Correct?

Comment: 2) The module that launches my userform is incredibly simple. It consists of

Comment: Sub conRegBox(control As IRibbonControl)
    Reg_Userform.Show
End Sub

Comment: ...so, would your CallUserform sub precede my .Show line of code or replace it? This would be the proper placement on this code?  Thanks!! Best, Dan

Comment: I never use the default instance of a UserForm. Instead of `F_UserForm.Show` I declare a variable for the instance I'm going to create. Usually it's a local variable as in `Dim frmUserForm As F_UserForm` followed by `Set frmUserForm = New F_UserForm` and `frmUserForm.Show`, but in this case I'm using a global variable `gf_UserForm`. Your userform takes the place of gf_UserForm in my routine.

Comment: I've added a version of my main code called `Sub conRegBox(control As IRibbonControl)` which is what you need, in addition to the public variable declaration for `gReg_Userform` and the userform module code added to `Reg_Userform`.